# How to save reads in a SPA with multiple routes that keep fetching the same data that hasn't changed since?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a single page app in VueJS with Firestore and I have different routes (served by different components with their own lifecycle) so I was wondering: if I were to call `onSnapshot` in all these different components, are the documents going to be fetched once by the first listener and then shared to the others using a local cache, or multiple times, one for each listener? All of this assuming that the documents are not changing.

And if that is true: is there some condition that must be satisfied for the cache to remain valid? For instance: maybe at least one listener must stay active otherwise the cache is invalidated. Meaning that going from one route to another would make this pointless since the component serving the previous route would be destroyed, invalidating the cache that the component serving the next route would use.

If not: what is the strategy commonly used by SPAs? Maybe a global store, such as Vuex, with global `onSnapshot` listeners that keep the store updated, with all components depending on that store?

I'm aware the Firestore SDK lets you chose whether you would like the data to be fetched from the cache or from the server but that's too much extra hassle in my opinion.
I'd like the library to do it for me: maybe the sdk could use cached data but if some document gets added/removed/modified online, then a realtime ping will invalidate the cache or maybe just those documents that have changed.